# Change this code to not construct the path from user-controlled data

Tags: laravel, sonarqube

```
public function exportRule(Request $request)
    {
        $checkRequest = DB::table('table')->where('id', $request->id)->count();
        if (!$checkRequest) {
            return "unable to find requested id";
        }
        $requestId = $request->id;
        $filename = "rules-" . date("mdyhis") . ".xlsx";
        $dir = $this->exportUrl . $requestId;
        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
                if ("." === $file || ".." === $file) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) {
                    rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
                } else {
                    unlink("$dir/$file");
                }
            }
            rmdir($dir);
        }
        Excel::store(
            new RulesExport(["request_id" => $requestId]),
            "$requestId/$filename",
            ExcelExcel::XLSX
        );
        $encypfile = hash_file(
            "sha256",
            $this->exportUrl . $requestId . "/$filename"
        );
        Storage::put("public/export/$requestId/$encypfile.txt", $encypfile);
        return Excel::download(
            new RulesExport(["request_id" => $requestId]),
            $filename,
            ExcelExcel::XLSX
        );
    }
```

how can i fix vulnerability on above program.error list below here...

1 Source: a user can craft an HTTP request with malicious content

2 A malicious value was previously assigned to field ‘request_id’

3 A malicious value can be assigned to variable ‘$requestId’

4 The malicious content is concatenated into the string

5 This concatenation can propagate malicious content to the newly created string

6 A malicious value can be assigned to variable ‘$dir’

7 Sink: this invocation is not safe; a malicious value can be used as argument

refactor the code above code.

Comment: +Tip: create a Validation Rule and sanitise data. (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation)

Comment: let me try , will update you

Comment: i am getting same issue. see link 
https://ibb.co/BB8c5cR